# whenever I try to use a for loop on a list to get the individual items it displays the first item only could some one help me with this?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

x = set()

display_list = []

count_list = []

while True:

```
items = input("> ").upper()
if items != "Q":
    x.add(items)
    count_list.append(items)
    count_list.count(items)

elif items == "Q":
    display_list.extend(x)
    for i in display_list:
        print(i)
        exit()
```

Comment: What do you think that `exit()` inside your loop is doing?

Comment: You need to outdent the `exit()` to the same level as the `for` loop. Then it will run *after* the `for` loop completes.